# How to retrieve a deleted voice note from iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, voice-memo

I recorded a 5 minute voice memo on my iPhone 5s and when I tapped "stop" I was prompted to give the memo a name. I named it and then I tapped "Delete" instead of "Save", and it disappeared! Noting that I was connected to my MacBook at the time of recording / naming the voice note.  Can I retrieve this recording?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a backup, no. Once it's deleted, it's gone from your device. Check the time on the last iCloud backup — if it's after you recording the audio but before you deleted it, you can restore from your iCloud backup to get the voice memo back.